# Enable Removal of offline_access on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I have an application that is registered with FB. Now I want to enable "Remove offline_access" from the app settings. Do I need to make any changes to my code? I am making server side OAuth Calls through FBClient. I am still suing "offline_access" permission in my code. Will it still work? Or do I have to make some changes in my code?

Also another question, is the FB access token expiration time of 60 days after the removal of "offline_access" a sliding expiration? Means when ever I login to FB with my App the access token expiry time will extend from that day to next 60 days?